# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=0, data=null} to activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera-intent

My app allows the user to press a button, it opens the camera, they can take a photo and it will show up in an `ImageView`. If the user presses back or cancel while the camera is open I get this force close - Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=0, data=null} to activity... so i am guessing the result=0 is the issue what would I need to insert to make this stop force closing?

Below is my code. I know I am forgetting something but just cant figure it out! (Admittedly I am about 2 weeks into learning android development). Thanks for any help!

```java
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.photostrippic1);

    ImageView photoButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.photostrippic1);



    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }

    });

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
```

I guess I would need a "else" in there somewhere but I dont exactly know to do that.

below is the logcat

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=0, data=null} to activity {photo.booth.app/photo.booth.app.PhotoboothActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2934)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2986)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1068)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at photo.booth.app.PhotoboothActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoboothActivity.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2930)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: In my case , the error was occurred due to the accidental turning of the option 'Do not keep activities` in developer option :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Adding this first conditional should work:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to also check that data != null (as well as the RESULT_CANCELED)

Comment: +1 works in fragment and activity, still Safer to check **if (data!=null )** , it guarantees the weird stuff of android old versions.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question. Error in the question says data=null. Hence accessing data without null check fails in the runtime. Actual answer is below by @Manto.

Answer (score 26):

For Kotlin Users don't forget to add ? in `data: Intent?`
like

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {}
```

Answer (score 17):

If the user cancel the request, the data will be returned as `NULL`. The thread will throw a `nullPointerException` when you call `data.getExtras().get("data");`. I think you just need to add a conditional to check if the data returned is null.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
       if (data != null)
       {         
           Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
           imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**For Kotlin Users**

You just need to add **?** with Intent in `onActivityResult` as the data can be `null` if user cancels the transaction or anything goes wrong. So we need to define data as `nullable` in `onActivityResult`

Just replace `onActivityResult` signature of SampleActivity with below:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using this:

1. Retrieve the father `Intent`.

   ```
   Intent intentParent = getIntent();
   ```
2. Convey the message directly.

   ```
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intentParent);
   ```

This prevents the loss of its activity which would generate a null data error.

Answer (score 4):

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) 
        {  
           Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
           imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } 
}
```

You can check if the resultCode equals RESULT_OK this will only be the case if a picture is taken and selected and everything worked. This if clause here should check every condition.

Answer (score 2):

this is my case

`startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);`

I defined two request code `PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST`and `SCAN_BARCODE_REQUEST` with the same value, eg.

`static final int BARCODE_SCAN_REQUEST = 1;`

`static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;`

this could also causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message show up for me because I was using the network on the main thread and new versions of Android have a "strict" policy to prevent that.  To get around it just throw whatever network connection call into an AsyncTask.

Example:

```
    AsyncTask<CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider, Integer, Void> task = new AsyncTask<CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider, Integer, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider... params) {
            AWSSessionCredentials creds = credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
            String id = credentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId();
            credentialsProvider.refresh();
            Log.d("wooohoo", String.format("id=%s, token=%s", id, creds.getSessionToken()));
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.execute(credentialsProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this question, I solved it through adding two conditions one is:

```
resultCode != null
```

the other is:

```
resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED
```

Comment: how about resultCode != RESULT_OK....? That way you check for all conditions that is not ok, including null

Comment: resultCode != null is invalid since resultCode is int !

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the called activity when it tries to return to the previous activity by "finishing." I was incorrectly setting the intent. The following code is Kotlin.

I was doing this:

```
        intent.putExtra("foo", "bar")
        finish()
```

When I should have been doing this:

```
        val result = Intent()
        result.putExtra("foo", "bar")
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result)
        finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I tried to pass a serializable model object. Inside that model, another model was a variable but that wasn't serializable. That's why I face this problem. Make sure all the model inside of an model is serializable.