# When getting the error: ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null}, What is the who=null?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);
```

In the paramters you got requestCode, resultCode and data.
But in the error you also get the "who".
What is this, and where is it coming from

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373755/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-reque

Comment: This is a general question. Yes I'm having issues with it now, but when I'm searching for the error, who=null, always shows up. I would like to know what it is

Comment: How can this be a duplicate? Yes there are 100 questions regarding ResultInfo error. I am asking what is the who=null since its not in the onActivityResult() parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ID of the activity. Often it's null. When your activity code is running, the activity has already been identified an it does not need to be reflected in the method signature.

If you're interested where the id comes from, here's some starting points for backtracing:

1. [`ResultInfo`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ResultInfo.java#36) that produces the string representation
2. [`sendActivityResult()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2037) that constructs `ResultInfo` with an id
3. [`startActivityForResult()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3429) that calls `sendActivityResult` with `mEmbeddedID`
4. `mEmbeddedID` initialized in [`attach()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#5211)
5. `attach()` called by [`ActivityThread`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2133)