# How can I get the user_id from the user currently logged in?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to get a private Playlist from the user currently logged in into the app.

```
SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();
api.setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());
SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();
Playlist playlist = spotify.getPlaylist(user_id, playlist_id);
```

How can I get user_id?

**EDIT**

I tried this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, data);
        if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
            SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();
            api.setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());
            SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();
            User user = spotify.getMe();
            Log.d("TAG", user.id);

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {de.test.spotifytest/de.test.spotifytest.activities.MainActivity}: retrofit.RetrofitError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get the user object in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) because it isn't possible to perform network actions on the main thread. The same applies to getting the users playlists.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Pager<Playlist>>{

    @Override
    protected Pager<Playlist> doInBackground(String... params) {
        Pager<Playlist> playlists = spotify.getPlaylists(spotify.getMe().id);
        return playlists;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pager<Playlist> playlistPager) {
       //do something with the playlists
    }
}
```

On main thread:

```
new MyTask().execute("");
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. BTW, you can also use AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
<your code> 
   }
});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library you're using, but it looks like the [spotify-web-api-android](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android) wrapper.

If so, you can retrieve the current user's user ID by calling the [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/) endpoint using SpotifyService's [getMe()](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/javadoc/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/SpotifyService.html#getMe()) method. getMe() will return a [User object](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/javadoc/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/models/User.html) that has a member called *id*.

Update: It seems the issue may not be related to the wrapper, but rather a general Android issue. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373755/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-reque) seems related.

Adding a check to see if the resultCode isn't RESULT_CANCELED before entering the if block may solve this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
  if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, data);
    ...
  }
}
```

Others use an additional resultCode == RESULT_OK, which to my understanding is valid as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the spotify-web-api-android wrapper. When I try to show the user id, it's giving me a runtimeException. I edited my question and added more code. What did i wrong?