# Failed to deliver Result to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, runtimeexception

I have an activity which opens a photo picker and crops it. Sometimes I get this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9162, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/22113 flg=0x1 }} to activity
```

This is my onActicvityResult(),

```
if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                beginCrop(result.getData());
            } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                handleCrop(resultCode, result);
            }
```

I want to know what does "who=null" mean? How can I prevent the crash?

Comment: You may be missing a parameter when calling an action through intent. Can you please share the code you have written for calling the intent?

Comment: @kapilthadani Actually I am using a library for this. And this is what I am doing, new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start(this);

Comment: maybe it's helpful to you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373755/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-reque

Comment: In your else if condition, add a condition for result==RESULT_OK. Because your handle crop method is getting executed even if result is cancelled!

Comment: Any idea, what "who=null" means?