# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131074, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

hi am trying to upload image using camera or from gallery where my below code is working perfectly on lollipop devices but getting an error in jelly bean. its showing  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131074, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity`

the below is my code in onActivity result

```
@
Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("gallery", "" + data.getData());
                performcropg(fileUri);
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                performcrop(fileUri);
            } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    // get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    saveToInternalStorage(selectedBitmap);
                    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedBitmap.getWidth(), selectedBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(selectedBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setShader(shader);
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                    c.drawCircle(selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, selectedBitmap.getHeight() / 2, selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);


                    img_role.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);

                }
            } else if (requestCode == pic_crop) {
                if (data != null) {

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    // get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    saveToInternalStorage(selectedBitmap);
                    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedBitmap.getWidth(), selectedBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(selectedBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setShader(shader);
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                    c.drawCircle(selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, selectedBitmap.getHeight() / 2, selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);


                    img_role.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? Facing the same exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Solution:** Add this too on validation `data != null && data.getData() != null` as

`if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && data != null && data.getData() != null)`

this will not give you crash but you cant get the image.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    fileUri = data.getData();
                    Log.d("gallery", "" + data.getData());
                    performcropg(fileUri);
                } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    fileUri = data.getData();
                    performcrop(fileUri);
                } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        // get the cropped bitmap
                        Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        saveToInternalStorage(selectedBitmap);
                        Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedBitmap.getWidth(), selectedBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(selectedBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setShader(shader);
                        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                        c.drawCircle(selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, selectedBitmap.getHeight() / 2, selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);


                        img_role.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);

                    }
                } else if (requestCode == pic_crop && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    if (data != null) {

                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        // get the cropped bitmap
                        Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        saveToInternalStorage(selectedBitmap);
                        Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedBitmap.getWidth(), selectedBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(selectedBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setShader(shader);
                        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                        c.drawCircle(selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, selectedBitmap.getHeight() / 2, selectedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);


                        img_role.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Full Demo working on all versions.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView camera, gallery;
    File photoFile;
    Uri uri;
    private final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private final static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);
        gallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            photoFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/myimage/save.jpg");
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            uri = data.getData();
            String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    String selecteadImage = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**activity_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which all devices you have tested??

Comment: @abhilnair is your issue fixed or you what short solution?

Comment: for some specific devices the issue are still same my code is working perfectly on some devices but in some data gets null

Comment: @abhilnair you try my full solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the check "if (data!=null )" to ensure that the code is functional under all odd conditions. This might help you solve this issue.

```
if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && data!=null ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

For more details on this you can refer [java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=0, data=null} to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373755/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-reque)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out camera permission in your manifest

```
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />-->
```