# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity NullPointerException when taking photo

Tags: java, android

For some reason, every now and then some users receive the following error when they take a photo through our company app. (There's a lot of legacy code I'm still getting my head around.)

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4832)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:190)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {w.h/w.h.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String w.h.images.imageFilename' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5471)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4776)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String w.h.images.imageFilename' on a null object reference
    at w.h.main.onActivityResult(main.java:6931)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8413)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5464)
    ... 12 more
```

We have around 150 users but only a handful who have this issue regularly. I found a handful of strings were being set to `null` incorrectly which helped resolve part of the issue however.

It crashes at the following part of `onActivityResult`:

```
// Deal with images once they've been taken
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(resultCode, resultCode, data);
  //Check if this is initiated. If not, well, initiate it.
  if(appointmentQuestions == null) appointmentQuestions = new appointmentQuestions(this);

  if(requestCode == CODE_NON_REPORT && resultCode == RESULT_LOGOUT) {

      forceLogout();

  } else if(requestCode == images.REQUEST_CAMERA || requestCode == images.REQUEST_VIDEO) {
      if (data != null) {
          // Build key for corresponding image instance
          String key = String.valueOf(apId);
          if (activeContentView == R.layout.missed_call) {
              key += "_missed_call";
          } else if (activeContentView == R.layout.part_collection) {
              key += "_part_collection";
          } else if (activeContentView == R.layout.transport) {
              key += "_transport";
          } else {

              int currentQuestion = appointmentQuestions.currentQuestionKey();

              key += "_q" + currentQuestion;
              if (appointmentQuestions.questionType(String.valueOf(currentQuestion)).equals("faultsList")) {
                  key += "_ftAppCode" + ftAppCode;
              }
          }
          key += "_" + activeMultiSection;
          Log.d("~~ key", key);

          // Get instance
          images instance = imagesInstances.get(key);

          Bitmap imageResized = null;
          String riDate = String.valueOf(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
          String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/hs/";

          imagePath += instance.imageFilename.endsWith("mp4") ? "videos" : "images";

          imagePath += "/" + instance.imageFilename;
```

I can't seem to find a reason for the instance to return as `null` on occasion.

Comment: Are you sure the imagesInstances  is non-null ?

Comment: @busetekin to my knowledge. It doesn't happen consistently. Sometimes the users can take a photo and save it perfectly fine. Othertimes, it take 7 or 8 attempts. I'm not sure what makes those instances different.

Comment: if imagesInstances comes to be null, the imageFileName will be null, in which case you get an nullpointer error. You can assign imagePath if  imagesInstances is non-null.You must add  null control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373755/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-reque might help.